# How to create trigger that gets value form table and update different table

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER after_game_status AFTER UPDATE ON games
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE player1,player2, score1, score2 INT DEFAULT NULL;
    IF ( NEW.status = 'finished') THEN
        SELECT account_id_player1, account_id_player2 INTO player1, player2 FROM games WHERE game_id = new.game_id;
        SELECT player1_score, player2_score INTO score1, score2 FROM scores WHERE game_id = new.game_id;
        IF( score1 > score2 ) THEN
            UPADTE games SET winner_account_id = player1 WHERE game_id = new.game_id;
        ELSE
            UPADTE games SET winner_account_id = player2 WHERE game_id = new.game_id;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER //
```

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'games SET winner_account_id = player1 WHERE game_id = new.game_id; ELSE UP' at line 9

Comment: A trigger cannot modify the contents of tables involved in the query that fired the trigger; if you want to modify the values, you should be using a BEFORE trigger, where you can just `SET NEW.winner_account_id = blah;` _(no UPDATE or WHERE involved, just a plain SET.)_ Similarly, the first SELECT is unnecessary since you can use `NEW.account_id_player1` and `NEW.account_id_player2` directly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo `UPADTE`, it should be `UPDATE`. In `IF` and `ELSE`, in two places the typo was there.

Working query will be:

```
IF( score1 > score2 ) THEN
    UPDATE games SET winner_account_id = player1 WHERE game_id = new.game_id;
ELSE
    UPDATE games SET winner_account_id = player2 WHERE game_id = new.game_id;
END IF;
```